# C: Copy array without knowing its type

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers

I have function, it receive pointer to array and pointer to function and should return new array with order defined by function passed in parameter.
My problem how I copy element of one array to another without knowing its type

```
void * scrambleArr(void * arr, int numElem, int elemSize, int (*func)(void*)) {
    void * newArr;
    int cPos, newPos,i;

    newArr = (void *)malloc(numElem*elemSize);

    for (i=0 ; i < numElem ; i++)
    {
        cPos = i*elemSize;
        newPos = func((char*)arr+cPos);
        *((char*)newArr+newPos) = *((char*)arr+cPos);
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

Function that passed in the last parameter

```
int posArrayBySize(void *el) {
    ARRAY* arr = (ARRAY *)el;
    return arr->size - 1;
}
```

And code in main:

```
int main( ) {
    ARRAY * arrSorted;
    int a[2] = {1,2};
    int b[3] = {1,1,1};
    int c[1] = {9};
    int d[4] = {3,3,3,3};
    ARRAY arr[4] = {{a,2},{b,3},{c,1},{d,4}};

    arrSorted =(ARRAY *)scrambleArr(arr,4,sizeof(ARRAY),posArrayBySize);

    free(arrSorted);
    return 0;
}
```

After running arrSorted contain garbage, 
Can someone point me, what i miss?

**Another option for me is not to copy, just to point one array to elements of other, is it possible?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

memcpy is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Just tried to replace code with `memcpy((char*)newArr+newPos,(char*)arr+cPos,elemSize);` without luck

Comment: You forgot to multiply newPos and cPos by elemSize.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, do you know if i can copy just addresses, without values?

Comment: @Alex: Yes: you *could* sort an array of pointers, but it changes the semantics in several ways. I worry that if you have to ask you may not be instantly away of all the consequences. Take a while to think about the life cycle of the data: when it comes into existence, when it goes away, who owns copies of the pointers and how do you know if those pointers are still valid or not. You're a programmer so you *can* figure all this out, but be careful.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work

```
*((char*)newArr+newPos) = *((char*)arr+cPos);
```

because you're dereferencing arr+cPos as it is char, so it will copy only the first byte.